# Annotation for an integer field - EF 4, MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this table:

```
[Table("MyTable", Schema = "MySchema")]
public class MyTable
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false
    public string LanguageID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false
    public byte YearID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public byte SIMSCodeID { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    public string Data { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    public int brformula { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see the last two fields are integers. What should be annotation for those so that I don't get this error when trying to access a row in this table with AJAX:

Message:

```
The 'brformula' property on 'MyTable' could not be set to a 'null' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Int32'.
```

Exception type:

```
System.Data.ConstraintException
```

Code line where the error happens:

```
MyTable myTable= db.MyTableDbSet.Find(langid, year, simscodeid);
```

Api controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetSIMSData(string langid, byte year, byte simscodeid)
{
    try
    {
        MyTable myTable = db.MyTableDbSet.Find(langid, year, simscodeid);

        if (MyTable == null)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, this.getSimsDataObject(false, myTable));
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, this.getSimsDataObject(true, myTable));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
    }
}
```

My AJAX call:

```
    getSIMSDataByAllParams: function (langId, year, simscodeid) {
        jq.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type: "GET",
            url: "/api/MyTable",

            data: {
                langid: langId,
                year: year,
                simscodeid: simscodeid,
                brformula: 0
            },

            dataType: "json",

            beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
                simsDataView.resetStatusAndErrorTf();
                simsDataView.setStatusMsg(simsDataView.getMessageByLang(langId, 'fetchingTreeNodeDataMsg'), constants.TEXT_COLOR_BLUE);
            },

            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                simsDataByAllParams = {};
                simsDataByAllParams = JSON.parse(data);
            },

            complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                if (simsDataByAllParams.hasData) {
                    tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(simsDataByAllParams.simsDataObject.Data);
                } else {
                    tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(simsDataView.getMessageByLang(langId, 'addEditorContentMsg'));
                }

                dbDirty = false;
                simsDataView.setStatusMsg(simsDataView.getMessageByLang(langId, 'treeNodeDataFetchedMsg'), constants.TEXT_COLOR_GREEN);
            },

            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                errorsMsgTxt.append(simsUtility.printAjaxError(langId, jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown));
            }
        });
    },
```

Note: Currently, the field in DB allows nulls, but I want it to be default value of 0.
Why it doesn't complain about UserID? It too is integer and allows nulls.

Comment: You want to allow a null int? Set the type to `int?`

Comment: Well, I don't know what would be right. I want it to have default value of 0.

Comment: @Vlad , are you using EF Code first?

Comment: The "right" is to reflect the db column nullablity. If it allows nulls, use nullable type. Having default 0 can be solved by initializer or in the constructor.

Comment: So remove the annotation for brformula field? Why it doesn't complain about UserID? It too is int and allows nulls.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server? If so, you can click on the column in the table design.. for `brformula` and below there is a row called 'Default Value or Binding' and you can set that to 0

Comment: Yes, I am not allowed by the DB admin to set default value. So If set to default, 0, it will not show this error, or?

Comment: If the default value is set to 0 on SQL Server then you will not receive this error.  So either ask your DB admin to do that for you, or you can set the default value for `brformula` to 0 in the constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience I do this either 1 or 2 ways.

Set the default value in the database, or set the default value in the constructor.

**From the database:**

If you are using SQL Server (that's what I use, but I couldn't see why this capability isn't available in other DBMS), you can click on the column in the table design.. for `brformula` and below there is a row called 'Default Value or Binding' and you can set that to 0.

**From the constructor:**

```
public class MyTable
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false
    public string LanguageID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false
    public byte YearID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public byte SIMSCodeID { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    public string Data { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    public int brformula { get; set; }

    public MyTable()
    {
        brformula = 0;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Well, neat idea. However I still get the same error. Could there be a problem with my API Controller? The one I use was for a table which didn't had brformula field. Now I set the same Controller to use the same Model class but with brformula. My API Controller was generated so I might be missing to set something

Comment: I can't tell if anything is wrong with your API controller because it is not a part of your question.

Comment: Yes, that is true. I though maybe because the generated API controller was for the previous Model not containing the brformula field.

Comment: But it doesn't matter. I generated new API controller, specifically for this new Model which contains brformula, still I get the same error.

Comment: Are you able to edit your question to show us the API method?

Comment: Along with how you're calling that API method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151619/discussion-between-bville-kid-and-vlad).